# ¿Cual es la expresion regular para aceptar solo letras,espacios, y caracteres especiales?

Tags: regex

esta solo me sirve para letras y espacios, pero no para caracteres especiales

```
regex:/^([a-zA-Z]+)(\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente agregas los caracteres que quieres que acepte entre corchetes.

Por ejemplo apra alfanuméricos:

```
/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
```

O si prefieres únicamente espacios en vez de cualquier blanco

```
/^[A-Za-z ]+$/
```

Ahora una forma corta de poner esto es usando

```
/^\w+$/
```

Esto representa caracteres alfanuméricos

Su contraparte es

```
\W
```

Caracteres no alfanuméricos

Así que podrías dejarlo en

```
/^[\w\W ]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no vas a aceptar numeros, puedes utilizar

```
print_r(!preg_match('/[0-9]{1,}/', 'as%##@1'));
```

Para ver si hay caracteres que no sean numeros

```
print_r(preg_match('/[^0-9]{1,}/', 'as%##@1'));
```